# How to realize the flutter gridview child height in different layout？

Tags: gridview, flutter-layout

**The layout height in figure is different, how to do？**
[image: gridview layout]

Comment: are you using a  `StaggeredGridView ` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can do this effect using a `StaggeredGridView` plugin [which can be found here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) it will allow you to construct grids of varying size depending on their content, or you can also customize the height of certain grids.